# headers.host gets hit by lots of domains that are not mine

Tags: node.js

I am getting many strange requests that have `req.headers.host` values that are not my domain.

```
var mc_domain = "mysubdomain.mydomain.com:8888";
var server = require('http').createServer(function (req, res) {
    if (req.headers.host !== my_domain) {
        console.log("not the host you are looking for " + req.headers.host);
        res.end();
        return;
    }
});
server.listen("8888");
```

console output
    not the host you are looking for abc.advertising.com
    not the host you are looking for parkingaddress1.com
    not the host you are looking for gotoinfo.info
    ...

What is going on, and what can I do to stop/reduce this? Is it just "welcome to the (wild) internet (west)", Or "You need a firewall", or some other foolishness.

Answer (score 0):

Eihter someone's DNS is resolving the other domain name to your IP address or domain is not setup properly. You can use a tool like dig to check the DNS settings at the DNS servers responsible for those domains (you can get them using whois).

You can look at this as problem, or as an opportunity. If I were you, I'd create a landing page for those users and try to sell my product/service.